# Download the file generated in Jenkins Job

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

My Jenkins Job runs a docker container for a task that executes a python script.

The python script takes some input and creates output in a file.

As of now, I have displayed the file content on the console, but I want a way in which
the required file gets downloaded while Jenkins job execution.

Can some help?

Answer (score 0):

So from your question I am assuming that this python script is being executed *inside* the container, and you are trying to access the output file that it creates from *outside* the container.

I would recommend *volume mounting* the output location inside the container to a location outside the container that Jenkins can access.

[Docker Volume Mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: Yes, the volumes are already mounted. I was searching for a download strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use archiveArtifacts step to attach file to build https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#-archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts
Then you can download through ui or curl